# AutoCompleteTextView - only one item at the dropdown menu after configuration changes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I set up `AutoCompleteTextView` like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    
    initSortingAutoCompleteTextView()
}

private fun initSortingAutoCompleteTextView() {
    val adapterSorting = ArrayAdapter(
        activityContext,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        sortingValues.map { it.title }
    )
    with(binding.sortingSelectAutocompleteText) {
        setAdapter(adapterSorting )
    }
}
```

It works fine:

[image]

But after configuration changes (orientation change for example) there is only one item:

[image]

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the implicit behavior of the `AutoCompleteTextView`/`ArrayAdapter`.

It has all of the items, but since it is trying to auto-complete it shows all the items that fit "Price" string.

One solution is to just disable the filtering.

```
class NonFilterArrayAdapter<T>(context: Context, @LayoutRes resource: Int, objects: List<T>) : ArrayAdapter<T>(context, resource, objects) {

    override fun getFilter() = NonFilter()

    class NonFilter : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?) = FilterResults()

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) = Unit
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, there is not attribute to disable it in XML/style for `AutoCompleteTextView` or `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"`?

Comment: It's the adapter, not the view so there is no XML attribute for that.